# Move hazard ratio values (and confidence intervals) left in forest() in metafor package

Tags: r, r-forestplot, metafor

I am just trying to move the hazard ratio/outcome column with its corresponding CI values to the left so that I can add a p-value to the right of the outcomes column, Is this possible?

Is there an easy way to find this argument and others like it in the R documentation for forest()?

```
#Forest Plot
label1 <- as.character(c("<50", "50 to <60", "60"))
label1 <- factor(label1, levels = unique(label1))
hazards1 <- c(1.42, 1.66, 2.85)
lower1 <- c(1.34, 1.50, 2.59)
upper1 <- c(1.51, 1.85, 3.13)
patient_num1 <- c(240000, 180000, 220000)
event_num1 <- c(2600, 1300, 2900)
forestplot1 <- data.frame(label1, hazards1, lower1, upper1, event_num1, patient_num1)
forestplot1$patient_num1 <- rev(forestplot1$patient_num1)

par(mar=c(4,4,1,2))
pdf(file = "figureex.pdf", width = 15, height = 8.5)
pdf.options(encoding='ISOLatin2.enc')
forest(rev(hazards1), ci.lb = rev(lower1), ci.ub = rev(upper1), slab = rev(label1), xlim = c(-4,0), 
       xlab = "Adjusted Hazard Ratio for Event", 
       refline = 1, annotate = T, ylim = c(-1, 29), ilab = cbind(forestplot1$patient_num1, rev(event_num1)),
       ilab.xpos=c(-1,-0.25), at = c(0.25, 0.5, 1, 2, 4, 6), rows = c(1:3),
       cex = 1, yaxs = "i")
text(-4, 27.29, pos = 4, "Variable")
text(-1.25, 27.67, pos = 4, "No. of \nPatients")
text(-0.45, 27.67, pos = 4, "No. of \nEvents")
text(5.05, 27.69, pos = 4, "Hazard Ratio \n(95% CI)")
dev.off()
```

Comment: To answer my own question, there is a new argument that has been added to the development version of the metafor package (for now), which allows the user to move the effect estimate and study columns. The new argument is textpos = c(1, 2), default values.

Comment: I've had the same issue. P-values are often needed to the right of estimates in publications. Another way around it is to split the plot window into 2 parts with `par(mfrow=c(1, 2))` and then add the p-values as a new plot with `text()`, etc.